# Как делать скрипты для андройд приложений?

Tags: android

Можно ли через genymotion или другой эмулятор скачать приложение и написать под него скрипт, наподобие в android studio "record...", только работающие в меню и других приложениях
Искал в интернете ADB genymotion и просто adb, но ничего, того что надо не нашел

Comment: Какой именно скрипт? Что этот скрипт должен выполнять? Какая вообще исходная задача?

Comment: Предположим на скаченное приложение из google маркета по нажимать пару кнопок или вписать там текст

Comment: @post_zeew Предположим на скаченное приложение из google маркета по нажимать пару кнопок или вписать там текст

Comment: Посмотрите с 22:35, то что надо?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csaXml4xtN8

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Вроде бы да, если это можно делать с приложением скаченным из маркета. А не подскажите как это называется??

Comment: Попробуйте, я не проверял. Я просто вам идею подбросил.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja - Хорошо. БОЛЬШОЕ ПРОСТО ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja не то, оно работает, если только приложение ты запускаешь, а не скачиваешь из интернета

Comment: @артемШеломенцев а чем вам [monkeyrunner](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkeyrunner/index.html)  не нравится?

Comment: @LexHobbit посмотрю что это